# Save specific objects from array in CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Imagine the Tinder app here, where the app will receive a list of user-profiles around the world. Now if the app user marks any profile as a favorite then I would like to save it in core data.

The way I have implemented is, Confirm decodable protocol to the NSManagedObject classes so I can easily parse the response from the user and create core data objects.

The issue is, when I save the context all the profiles are saved and what I want is only favorite profiles should be saved.

Here is a code snippet of how my classes look like.

```
// MARK: - Name
class Name:NSManagedObject, Codable {
    @NSManaged var title: String
    @NSManaged var first: String
    @NSManaged var last: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case title = "title"
        case first = "first"
        case last = "last"
    }
    
    init() {
        super.init(entity: NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: String.init(describing: Name.self), in: PersistenceController.shared.context)!, insertInto: PersistenceController.shared.context)
    }
    
    @objc
    private override init(entity: NSEntityDescription, insertInto context: NSManagedObjectContext?) {
        super.init(entity: entity, insertInto: context)
    }

    convenience init(title: String, first: String, last: String) {
        self.init()
        self.title = title
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
    }
    
    // MARK: - Decodable
    required convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        
        self.init()
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        title = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .title) ?? ""
        first = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .first) ?? ""
        last = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .last) ?? ""
    }
    
    // MARK: - Encodable
    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(title, forKey: .title)
        try container.encode(first, forKey: .first)
        try container.encode(last, forKey: .last)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, if you create an instance of a NSManagedObject subclass and call save() on the context the object will be saved. The code where you handle the favourite logic isn't included here but to me it looks like you need to separate the json data from the data you want to persist using Core Data by having 2 separate types

Comment: The favorite is just a bool and once it's a status change I save the context.

Comment: With all decoded objects...